# XAML Textbox Border when ReadyOnly

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am having the same issue in the link below. There are no answers for this. It was asked 1 year ago

[XAML textbox border goes away when changing isreadonly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18329310/xaml-textbox-border-goes-away-when-changing-isreadonly)

Can someone help me ? This is my Existing CSS for Textbox

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="StandardTextBox">
    <Style.Resources>
        <fawgCommon:ControlBackgroundConverter x:Key="BackgroundConverter" />
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="telerik:StyleManager.Theme" Value="{DynamicResource Theme}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource BackgroundConverter}">
                <Binding />
                <Binding Mode="OneTime"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource CurrentThemeForegroundBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="CaretBrush" Value="{DynamicResource CurrentThemeForegroundBrush}" />
</Style>
```

Comment: if the question is the same, then you need to correctly tag your question, `WPF` tag is not for WinPhone questions.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why this could be a problem, but in a basic demo you can just use some Trigger listening to `IsReadOnly` and set the Border for the TextBox normally:

```
<TextBox IsReadOnly="True"  BorderThickness="1">
    <TextBox.Style>
       <Style TargetType="TextBox">
          <Style.Triggers>
             <Trigger Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/>                    
             </Trigger>
          </Style.Triggers>
       </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

The above example sets the `IsReadOnly` to `true` initially, so some Blue border will be shown.

***Update***:

for the code you posted, it should be like this:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="StandardTextBox">
  <Style.Resources>
    <fawgCommon:ControlBackgroundConverter x:Key="BackgroundConverter" />
  </Style.Resources>
  <Style.Triggers>
     <Trigger Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True">
         <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/>
         <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
     </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
  <Setter Property="telerik:StyleManager.Theme" Value="{DynamicResource Theme}"/>
  <Setter Property="Background">
    <Setter.Value>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource BackgroundConverter}">
            <Binding />
            <Binding Mode="OneTime"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
  <Setter Property="Foreground" 
          Value="{DynamicResource CurrentThemeForegroundBrush}" />
  <Setter Property="CaretBrush" 
          Value="{DynamicResource CurrentThemeForegroundBrush}" />
</Style>
```

Comment: I added my code above. can you please help me fix in the above code ?

Comment: I tried that on my own before. Its not working. but interesting thing is, if I click on textbox, border is appearing and If I click on another textbox, border is disappearing

Comment: @WPFRookie I also tried the code first, it almost works. When the mouse is over the TextBox, the Border will be faded out a little (maybe caused by the default animation). I cannot reproduce the behavior you described. Is your TextBox just a standard one and does not have any other code (except what you posted) involved?

Comment: Kong Yes, its standard textbox and it doesnt have any other code